# Optimizing dict of set of tuple of ints with Numba?

Tags: python, cython, numba

I am learning how to use Numba (while I am already fairly familiar with Cython). How should I go about speeding up this code? Notice the function returns a dict of sets of two-tuples of ints. I am using IPython notebook. I would prefer Numba over Cython.

```
@autojit
def generateadj(width,height):
    adj = {}
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            s = set()
            if x>0:
                s.add((x-1,y))
            if x<width-1:
                s.add((x+1,y))
            if y>0:
                s.add((x,y-1))
            if y<height-1:
                s.add((x,y+1))
            adj[x,y] = s
    return adj
```

I managed to write this in Cython but I had to give up on the way data is structured. I do not like this. I read somewhere in Numba documentation that it can work with basic things like lists, tuples, etc.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np

def generateadj(int width, int height):
    cdef int[:,:,:,:] adj = np.zeros((width,height,4,2), np.int32)
    cdef int count

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            count = 0
            if x>0:
                adj[x,y,count,0] = x-1
                adj[x,y,count,1] = y
                count += 1
            if x<width-1:
                adj[x,y,count,0] = x+1
                adj[x,y,count,1] = y
                count += 1
            if y>0:
                adj[x,y,count,0] = x
                adj[x,y,count,1] = y-1
                count += 1
            if y<height-1:
                adj[x,y,count,0] = x
                adj[x,y,count,1] = y+1
                count += 1
            for i in range(count,4):
                adj[x,y,i] = adj[x,y,0]
    return adj
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `numba` supports such Python data structures as `dict`s and `set`s, it does so in *object mode*. From the `numba` glossary, object mode is defined as:

> A Numba compilation mode that generates code that handles all values
>   as Python objects and uses the Python C API to perform all operations
>   on those objects. Code compiled in object mode will often run no
>   faster than Python interpreted code, unless the Numba compiler can
>   take advantage of loop-jitting.

So when writing `numba` code, you need to stick to built-in data types such as arrays. Here's some code that does just that:

```
@jit
def gen_adj_loop(width, height, adj):
    i = 0
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if x > 0:
                adj[i,0] = x
                adj[i,1] = y
                adj[i,2] = x - 1
                adj[i,3] = y
                i += 1

            if x < width - 1:
                adj[i,0] = x
                adj[i,1] = y
                adj[i,2] = x + 1
                adj[i,3] = y
                i += 1

            if y > 0:
                adj[i,0] = x
                adj[i,1] = y
                adj[i,2] = x
                adj[i,3] = y - 1
                i += 1

            if y < height - 1:
                adj[i,0] = x
                adj[i,1] = y
                adj[i,2] = x
                adj[i,3] = y + 1
                i += 1
    return
```

This takes an array `adj`. Each row has the form `x y adj_x adj_y`. So for the pixel at `(3,4)`, we'd have the four rows:

```
3 4 2 4
3 4 4 4
3 4 3 3
3 4 3 5
```

We can wrap the above function in another:

```
@jit
def gen_adj(width, height):
    # each pixel has four neighbors, but some of these neighbors are
    # off the grid -- 2*width + 2*height of them to be exact
    n_entries = width*height*4 - 2*width - 2*height
    adj = np.zeros((n_entries, 4), dtype=int)
    gen_adj_loop(width, height, adj)
```

This function is very fast, but incomplete. We must convert `adj` to a dictionary of the form in your question. The problem is that this is a very slow process. We must iterate over the `adj` array and add each entry to a Python dictionary. This cannot be jitted by `numba`.

So the bottom line is this: the requirement that the result is a dictionary of tuples really constrains how much you can optimize this code.

Comment: Note that `numba` has added support for numerous features since the date of this answer.