# Numba-compatible replacement for dict

Tags: python, dictionary, numba

I am trying to solve a series of Bellman value functions without using dictionaries, since I believe that dictionaries are not supported in Numba (e.g. see [Optimizing dict of set of tuple of ints with Numba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889463/optimizing-dict-of-set-of-tuple-of-ints-with-numba)). In particular, the dictionary structure in my naive representation (below) is useful because I need to perform operations on both the keys as well as the values. What data structures should I use, or how should I set up my problem so that I can still use Numba?

Explicitly: I am filling in a set of recursively defined value functions, where they are meant to model 'job experience' over various 'sectors' at a given time. For example, if there are 2 sectors and it is t=3, the experience allocations, i.e. the possible states at t=3, are (3,0), (2,1), (1,2), (0,3). For each of these experience allocations there is some value associated with them. The recursion comes from the fact that at t=2, the value can be recursively defined from the values of 'reachable' states at t=3. For example, at t=2, the value of (2,0) is a function of two values at t=3, (3,0) and (2,1), since those are the 'reachable' experience levels by adding 1 to experience in either sector.

This is very straightforward to code if I define a dictionary with keys that are tuples of form (time, experience), since I can just 'read' the experience (tuple), find out what are the 'reachable' key values in the next period (by adding 1 to each value of the experience tuple), call the corresponding values, and evaluate the value at the current time using the recursive relationship.

However, I do not believe dictionaries work in Numba, so what sort of data structure should I use instead, that still lets me pull in a 'key' and a 'value'? In general the problem will be too large for me to make e.g. a 2-D array of size N^T for N sectors for time T. Also, for my desired 'output', I want the full 'dictionary' of values, since I will presumably calculate this filled in dictionary once and then re-using its values numerous times.

Comment: Not a trivial undertaking, but you could wrap a c based hash table library using `cffi` and access that from numba.  Example using khash here, not something I've actually tried. https://github.com/synapticarbors/khash_numba

Comment: I saw that module too while searching for my question. So, to the best of your knowledge, at the moment there is no existing dict analogue that works with numba and is strictly python? I haven't used numba too much so I'm not the most familiar with its state of development/best practices.

Comment: Correct, in nopython mode dicts are unsupported.  issue tracker - https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2096