# Python Numba optimize function with dictionary of sets

Tags: python, optimization, numba

I'm trying to perform 100K + monte-carlo simulations and call a function `simulate` many times to perform this. I'm investigating using Nubma to do this and could use some help, specifically I need to do intersections and unions of sets.

This is a minimum working example of the code I'm trying to optimise. It seems that Numba does not support dictionaries of sets, and if I were to use dictionaries of numpy arrays, then I do not have access to `np.intersect1d` and `np.union1d` any help would be appreciated in transforming this to Numba, or perhaps it is a bad fit for Numba optimization?

```
import random
import numpy as np

from numba import types, jit
from numba.typed import Dict, List

n_positions = 100
position_coverage = 10
min_dist = 5

n_ids = 5

near_dict = {x: set(range(x, x + position_coverage)) 
                if x < n_positions - position_coverage else 
                set(range(x, n_positions)) for x in range(n_positions)}
# near_dict = {0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 1: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
close_dict = {x: set(range(x, x + min_dist)) 
                if x < n_positions - position_coverage + min_dist else 
                set(range(x, n_positions)) for x in range(n_positions)}
# close_dict = {0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2: {2, 3, 4, 5, ...

near_dict = {k: near_dict[k] for k in random.sample(near_dict.keys(), n_ids)}

@jit(nopython=True)
def simulate(near_dict, close_dict):
    out_dict = {}
    to_pos = None
    to_close = set()
    for id, near in sorted(near_dict.items(), key=lambda x: random.random()):
        if to_pos is None:
            _ixs_to = near
        else:
            to_close |= close_dict[to_pos]
            _ixs_to = near - to_close
        if not _ixs_to:
            return {} # failed no reachable positions
        to_pos = random.choice(tuple(_ixs_to))
        out_dict[id] = to_pos
    return out_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    simulate(near_dict, close_dict)
```

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to simulate please? It is bit hard to decipher from the code alone.

Comment: Also, is the close_dict always in this(or similar) shape? From what I can see it is most likely possible(if not better) to remove it alltogether and instead use a function to get the values on the go. Or if numba complains, inline the function. The set operations will always be slow so if you are going for a performance improvement, it will most likely be a good idea to figure a way how to do away with them.

Comment: @Shamis I'm simulating a variant of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Placing nodes on a graph, where `near_dict={id1: pos1, id2: pos2, id3: pos3}` where each node should be moved to a position within its available positions `near_dict[pos]`, and not within `close_dict[pos]`. So nodes are repositioned within some constraints,

Close  dict is always in this shape, and values are precomputed, I'm not sure if it would be faster to calculate on the go. 

I'm not sure how to do away with sets here

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889463/optimizing-dict-of-set-of-tuple-of-ints-with-numba)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078628/using-dictionaries-with-numba-njit-function) might be relevant. In the end I don't think that you can use numba without a sacrifice of the python's flexibility and structure. Your problem might be better suited for a different language. Also a question - what is the usual size of the graph? Is the graph big, or is it simply the issue of the number of nodes you wish to move aroud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transforming to Numba:

This was a tedious one since Numba imposes many limitations. It would definitely be better to post this code step by step, however then the answer would be much too long.
In short, to convert a code to Numba and use its full optimization with `nopython`, you need to follow approximately these rules. 
**Disclaimer**: I'm not a numba expert and this section is just observation based:

- No objects outside of the basic ones and numpy. This means no sets and no dictionaries.
- Functions are allowed only to return single value, not an array.
- Everything needs to be typed or easy enough for Numba to infer the type automatically.

There are probably more. I'm not too sure. So basically as the name suggests, if you go the nopython route, forget that you're in python. The code either needs to be really straightforward(as in several loops with a simple computation) or you will have to butcher the code to oblivion. (Or there is some other trick I've not found yet.)
**Edit:** I have found a trick - numba now supports the dictionary even in nojit as long as you declare all types beforehands. It also supports sets. However it can't store sets in a dictionary so in your case you would have to first store the sets in an array and then use a dictionary as a sort of a translation table from id to an index. Not impossible but definitely not straightforward.

The code, that most likely works. However a part of it is deprecated, since I gave up on trying to get rid of the last `[]` in favor of a numpy array. Also it isn't optimized nor did I measured performance.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
n_positions = 100
position_coverage = 10
min_dist = 5
n_ids = 5
near_keys = random.sample(range(n_positions), n_ids)


@jit(nopython=True)
    def simulate(near_keys):
    to_pos = -1
    _ixs_to = np.zeros(1)
    to_return = []
    for id in sorted(near_keys, key=lambda x: random.random()):
        if id < n_positions:
            near = np.arange(id, id + position_coverage)
        else:
            near = np.arange(id, n_positions)

        print(id, near)
        if to_pos == -1:
            _ixs_to = near
        else:
            to_close = []
            a = int(n_positions - position_coverage + min_dist)
            to_pos = int(to_pos)
        if to_pos < a:
            pos_values = np.arange(to_pos, to_pos + min_dist)
        else:
            pos_values = np.arange(to_pos, n_positions)

        for i in pos_values:
            if not i in to_close:
                to_close.append(i)

        _ixs_to = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int64)
        for i in near:
            if not i in to_close:
                _ixs_to = np.append(_ixs_to, i)
        if _ixs_to[0] == 0:
            _ixs_to = _ixs_to[1:]

        if _ixs_to.ndim == 0:
            return [-1] # failed no reachable positions
        np.random.rand()
        to_pos = np.random.choice(_ixs_to)
        to_return.append(id)
        to_return.append(to_pos)
        return to_return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(simulate(near_keys))
```

So what happened to your reasonably nice, if maybe needlessly complicated code?

First, I've replaced **sets** with generating functions: 
`near_dict = {x: set(range(x, x + position_coverage)) if x < n_positions - position_coverage else set(range(x, n_positions)) for x in range(n_positions)}`
became

```
def get_near(x):
    if x < n - position_coverage:
        return set(range(x, x + position_coverage))
    else:
        return set(range(x, n_positions)
```

Then I rewrote the unions and differences of the sets in a way that doesn't require them. This was done by iterating through the arrays and checking for the values to either remove or add them. Note, that this is the part where this is most likely slower, unless the union operation in pure python is slower then the unoptimized naive union I did. If you wish to optimize the code, this is one of the places to start.

Unfortunately, while njit numba allows for parameters to be arrays, it [doesn't allow a return value of a function to be an array](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.16.0/arrays.html). Because we need the arrays the next step was to inline any of the function that was returning an array in the original code.

While reading through the docs, I noticed additional thing: Numba doesn't allow an array creation in `nopython` and falls back to an object mode in such a case. That means that you would need to recycle arrays instead of recreating them in the code above to fully leverage this mode.

The last step was to iron out all the type mismatches and to ensure that everything worked together. A result is a code that Numba's `nopython` is willing to run which is unfortunately rather messy and which doesn't leverage nearly any of the conveniences of Python. It is also woefully unoptimized. However if you wish to apply numba and subsequently have the *cheap* parallelization it provides this is most likely necessary. If someone more familiar with numba corrects me and points me in a direction that is more user-friendly, I will gladly remove this answer as misleading.

To sum up, while Numba is definitely a powerful tool, I'm not too certain if it is reasonable to use it for your project since your main issue is not a simple repeated mathematical operation but a repeated iteration of a logic that is a little more complicated then Numba prefers.

Few tips:

- I would have go at profiling and optimizing your code first. It is easier to profile code before you start doing parallel shenanigans. If that proves insufficient **that** would be the moment to try and:
- look into the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) python library, if this kind of speedup would be enough for you. If that isn't enough, then:
- try rewriting your already optimized code for numba and finally, if that still isn't enough:
- give C, Rust, C++, Java or something similar a go. You might be surprised.

**Final word:** While I'm reasonably sure about the way I replaced the sets with functions which I then inlined, I'm not completely sure I got it right. Caution is recommended.